# Update switch state render by map in react

Tags: reactjs

I am doing my task to change status by call api and get new data but i don't know how exactly it's can be done because it's render by an arrays.map. Sorry for my bad english, please take a look to the example i provided. Thanks a lot!

```
const Foo = () => {
  const [foos, setFoos] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    try {
      // where i call api backend to change status, assume that it called success and i get new status
      // what should i do here to set new status to display in view
    } catch(e) {
      console.error('Exception ' + e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // where i call api to set Foos, assume that it called success
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {foos.map((foo, i) =>
        <div key={i}>
          <p>{foo.id}</p>
          <p className={foo.status ? 'success': 'failed'} onClick={() => handleClick()}>{foo.status}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: whats the actual Q ... are you facing any trouble or any errors ?

Comment: I guess make the backend API request, process the response, and call `setFoos`? ‍♂️ What have you tried? What are you fetching? What needs to be updated?

Comment: @DrewReese uhm, in useEffect you can see that i called an API and setFoos successfuly. Foos now displayed in view by using foos.map. But when i want to change status of only one foo by call another API for example http://localhost:3000/foo/1/changeStatus, if the call success what should i do to display the new status to view because it's render by map? Sorry for any confused!

Comment: You process the response and update state! Updating state/props triggers component rerenders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to update the status of a given `foo` when it is clicked?

Try this:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const [foos, setFoos] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (fooIndex) => {
    try {
      const newStatus = ...; // Do something here to get new status
      const newFoos = [...foos]; // shallow copy foos
      newFoos[fooIndex] = { // shallow copy newFoos[fooIndex] element
        ...newFoos[fooIndex],
        status: newStatus,
      };
      setFoos(newFoos);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error('Exception ' + e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // where i call api to set Foos, assume that it called success
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {foos.map((foo, i) =>
        <div key={i}>
          <p>{foo.id}</p>
          <p className={foo.status ? 'success': 'failed'} onClick={() => handleClick(i)}>{foo.status}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

It comes down to just sending the index of the `foo` that was clicked to the `handleClick` callback and then using that to update the correct `foo`.

Comment: `foos[fooIndex].status = newStatus;`/`foos.status = newStatus;` is a state mutation. When updating the `foos` state it necessarily needs to be a new array reference.

Comment: that mean  i need to reset (the best word i think) the whole Foos?

Comment: @DrewReese, not necessarily. The call at the end with `setFoos` should be enough to update the state

Comment: Not necessarily, if the `foos` state reference never changes then React will very likely bail out of rerendering. See [Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update). Always shallow copy the state that is being updated so you ensure new references are returned for reconciliation purposes.

Comment: @DrewReese you are absolutely correct. I just tried a test and noticed this also. It seems the entire list needs to be a different reference for react to react...

Comment: Use caution with `foo.status = newStatus; setFoos([...foos]);` as this still mutates the previous state object, the `[...foos]` new array reference will likely mask the mutation though. Sometimes this is benign, sometimes it causes issues.